# Day count - calculation and remove the minus

Tags: php, html, date

From the calculation returns -30.
How can I remove the minus, so it just returns 30

```
$days = (strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) - strtotime($info['expiredate'])) / (60 * 60 * 24)

echo $days
```

What is the best approach?

Comment: what does `$info['expiredate']` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you are sure the calculation is always in the right order, you can just use the `abs()` function to always display the positive number.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics `x-y == -(y-x)`...
Flip the order of subtraction.